# How can I get back real value from cumulative sum in pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

Suppose, I've a DataFrame df.

```
>>> DATA = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'salary':[1200,2300,2400,3620,2100] } 
>>> df = DataFrame(DATA)
>>> df
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    2300
2   3    2400
3   4    3620
4   5    2100
```

From this DataFrame df, I can get a new DataFrame df1 with cumulative sum of salary

```
>>> df['salary'] = df['salary'].cumsum() 
>>> df
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    3500
2   3    5900
3   4    9520
4   5   11620
```

This is very common scenario.

Now, What about if I am given df1 and I have to find df.

```
   id  salary            id  salary
0   1    1200             0   1    1200
1   2    3500             1   2    2300
2   3    5900     ==>     2   3    2400
3   4    9520             3   4    3620
4   5   11620             4   5    2100
```

All I have to find actual salary for all id from its cumulative sum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> df
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    3500
2   3    5900
3   4    9520
4   5   11620
>>> df['salary'] = df['salary'].diff().fillna(df['salary'].iloc[0])
>>> df
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    2300
2   3    2400
3   4    3620
4   5    2100
```

although `.fillna` is not efficient in here, because it is only the first value which comes out null. so, you just need to replace the first value with cumulative value at `.iloc[0]`.

Comment: what about if cumulative sum happens two times.. 1st time 0 to 2 and second time 3 to 4?

Comment: oh.. I see. i just need to split df int two dataframe

Comment: I don't think you need to do this in one line (as you say yourself): `s = df['salary']; df['salary'] = s.diff(); df['salary'].iloc[0] = s.iloc[0]`.

Comment: Actually posted another answer if there are NaN, it's not so bad.

Comment: This answer doesn't work if there are NaN values in many places. Your `fillna()` also is not working properly!

Answer (score 0):

If the Series/column contains NaN then you need to take a little more care.

```
In [11]: df.loc[2, 'salary'] = np.nan

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    2300
2   3     NaN
3   4    3620
4   5    2100

In [13]: df['salary'].cumsum()
Out[13]:
0    1200
1    3500
2     NaN
3    7120
4    9220
Name: salary, dtype: float64

In [14]: df['salary'] = df['salary'].cumsum()
```

We can actually get back to the original, as NaN's are skipped over, we just skip over them:

```
In [21]: s
Out[21]:
0    1200
1    3500
3    7120
4    9220
Name: salary, dtype: float64

In [22]: d = s.diff()

In [23]: d.iloc[0] = s.iloc[0]

In [24]: d
Out[24]:
0    1200
1    2300
3    3620
4    2100
Name: salary, dtype: float64
```

Now we can just assign this back to the salary column (missing values become NaN):

```
In [25]: df['salary'] = d

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   id  salary
0   1    1200
1   2    2300
2   3     NaN
3   4    3620
4   5    2100
```

Note: if the index is not unique this won't work, but you can trick it with something like:

```
df.loc[df['salary'].notnull(), "salary"] = s  # or s.values
```